# spring redis wrong result

Tags: spring, redis

I am using Spring Redis with the @Cacheable annotiation for two methods. When I call one method I am getting a result cached for the other method.

How can it happen that I get the result from the wrong cache while I configured a different cache for each method using the @Cachebale annotation?

Setup: Spring Version 4.1.6. Redis data 1.5 and Redis client 2.7.0.

Example code:

```
@Cacheable("test1")
    public List<String> findSgsns() {
}

@Cacheable("test2")
    public List<String> findSgsns2() {
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was sloved by adding following setting to spring configuration (set usePrefix):

```
<bean
    id="cacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
    c:template-ref="redisTemplate">
    <property name="usePrefix" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring use `SimpleKeyGenerator` to generate the key if you don't specify it in the `@Cacheable` annotation.

```
public class SimpleKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

@Override
public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) 
{
    return generateKey(params);
}

/**
 * Generate a key based on the specified parameters.
 */
public static Object generateKey(Object... params) {
    if (params.length == 0) {
        return SimpleKey.EMPTY;
    }
    if (params.length == 1) {
        Object param = params[0];
        if (param != null && !param.getClass().isArray()) {
            return param;
        }
    }
    return new SimpleKey(params);
}
}
```

As there is no method arguments in both of your methods (`findSgsns() and findSgsns2()`), it essentially will generate the same cache key for both methods.

You've already found a solution which basically utilize `usePrefix` property in the `redisTemplate` bean, which essentially add you value ( namely, "test1" and "test2") you specified in your `@Cacheable` annotation when it forms the cache key in Redis. I would like to mention 2 more alternatives for the sake of completeness here:

1. Specify your own key for each method (Note: you can use Spring EL to specify your keys):

   ```
   @Cacheable(value = "test1", key = "key1")
   public List<String> findSgsns() {
   }

   @Cacheable(value = "test2", key = "key2")
   public List<String> findSgsns2() {
   }
   ```
2. Build a custom key generator, and below is sample key generator which takes method name into redis cache key generation (Note: the custom key generator will take effect automatically by extending `CachingConfigurerSupport` class):

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

   @Bean
   public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
       return new KeyGenerator() {
           @Override
           public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb.append(target.getClass().getName());
               sb.append(method.getName());
               for (Object obj : params) {
                   sb.append(obj.toString());
               }
               return sb.toString();
           }
       };
   }

   }
   ```